# run a python function with arguments

Tags: python

With the [ncinfo](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/blob/master/utils/ncinfo) command, I can view the contents of a netcdf file from a csh (Eg. `ncinfo test.nc`). The ncinfo command actually calls the python function 
[here](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/blob/master/netCDF4/utils.py#L427). My question is: How do I use the ncinfo function directly from a python shell?

I tried the

```
from netCDF4.utils import ncinfo
ncinfo()
```

but I can't figure out how to pass the filename 'test.nc' to the function.
Any idea?

Edit: Based on the comments, I think the question now is

How to 'fake' an argument inside a python shell to feed a function which use `getopt.getopt` and `sys.argv` to accept arguments?

Comment: If you follow the link, the [ncinfo](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/blob/master/netCDF4/utils.py#L427) does not accept an function argument in python..

Comment: Then how do you expect to pass the filename? The arguments come from `sys.argv`... So, you'd have to use `subprocess`

Comment: If you are wanting to programmatically inspect the data, why don't you use `netCDF4.utils.Dataset()`, which does all the heavy lifting and takes a `filename`. As pointed out `ncinfo()` is the cmd-line interface.

Comment: I assume you mean `netCDF4.Dataset('test.nc')`. It works! But I still want to know if there's any way to 'fake' a command-line argument inside a python shell? I guess `subprocess` is a solution, but it calls the python script wrapper instead of the original function.

Comment: At an IPython shell prompt you could say `run /path/to/ncinfo  test.nc`.   Or more generally you could manually set `sys.argv[1:]` before calling `ncinfo()`

Comment: If a function uses sys.argv[1:] to get arguments, just put a new value in there...sys.argv.append("test.nc")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Alan Leuthard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7637879/alan-leuthard) and [jez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3019689/jez) point out in the comments, one can manually modify sys.argv (didn't know it's mutable) before calling the function. So a working solution is

```
from netCDF4.utils import ncinfo
backup = sys.argv
sys.argv = ['','test.nc']
ncinfo()
sys.argv = backup
```